# TMUX: how to make new window stay when start shell-command quits?

Tags: shell, tmux

In tmux command mode, the following creates new window and opens vim inside:

```
:new-window vim
```

When you quit vim, the window is also closed. Is there a way to make it stay?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`tmux` has an option for this: `remain-on-exit`:

```
tmux set remain-on-exit on
```

Comment: This makes that window dead. Do you know how to make it go back to shell?

Comment: @Amjith: `:new-window "/bin/sh -c 'vim; exec bash'"`

Comment: Shell it be setw remain-on-exit on ?

Answer (score 4):

I realise this is a long dead question. But I'm a recent user of tmux and I had this same question. It turns out that you might want to do this:

```
tmux new-session bash -l
```

That gets you a bash window (login shell). Then, run whatever commands you want. When they're done, they return to a command prompt, like you expect. I think a lot of people are looking for an interactive 'screen'-like behaviour. This is an easy way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I use send-keys so that it "types" the command into the shell.  Here's my `get.all` script, which fires up many commands, some of which I may need to interact with after they're done (and the ones I don't, have `exit`):

```
#!/bin/sh
tmux att -t get ||
tmux \
  new -s get -n emacs \; \
  send-keys 'get.emacs' C-m \; \
  neww -n git \; \
  send-keys 'get.git' C-m \; \
  neww -n mini \; \
  send-keys 'get.mini' C-m \; \
  neww -n port \; \
  send-keys 'get.port' C-m \; \
  neww -n rakudo \; \
  send-keys 'get.rakudo' C-m \; \
  neww -n neil \; \
  send-keys 'get.neil && get.neil2 && exit' C-m \; \
  neww -n red \; \
  send-keys 'get.red && exit' C-m \; \
  neww -n cpan \; \
  send-keys 'get.cpan && exit' C-m \; \
  selectw -t emacs
```

Answer (score 1):

Moving good comment of @Jo So to a separate answer.

This command drops to shell once the first `ls -la` finishes:

   `tmux new-window "/bin/sh -c 'ls -la; exec bash'"`

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to quit the process in the new window normally (as in, proper exit), then `tmux new-window "vim ; exec bash"` would mostly be fine.

However, if you would intend to quit the new process via system interrupt (SIGINT for example). You will have to use `trap`.

`tmux new-window "bash -c 'trap \"bash\" INT; tail -f foo'"`

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to create a new window and run a command in it, this might work better

```
new-window \; send-keys 'vim' Enter ;\ last-window
```