# Is it possible to quit tmux, while "keeping" the window in the terminal

Tags: tmux

**Use case**

I run command over a bastion in SSH and since the connection can be dropped we are using `tmux` or `screen`.

For short commands I'm using `send-keys`, let's say I'm using a command like `kubectl get pods`. I'd like to keep the output of this command but terminate the tmux session.

Using `remain-on-exit` is not what I'm looking for as it keeps a dead window.

I've seen those question already

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17116/prevent-pane-window-from-closing-when-command-completes-tmux
- [TMUX: how to make new window stay when start shell-command quits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311583/tmux-how-to-make-new-window-stay-when-start-shell-command-quits/5312607#5312607)

Answer (score 3):

> I'd like to keep the output of this command but terminate the tmux session.

I use this in my **~/.tmux.conf**, and now when I exit my running shell, pane output is saved to unique log file:

```
set -g remain-on-exit
set-hook pane-died 'capture-pane -S - -E - ; save-buffer "$HOME/logs/tmux/tmux-saved.#{host_short}-#{session_id}:#{window_id}:#{pane_id}-#{pane_pid}-#{client_activity}.log"; delete-buffer; kill-pane'
```

Comment: Hi interesting approach, however I couldn't get it to work. Is there a specific version of tmux to be used.

Comment: Here is a very slightly modified version I use with tmux-2.8:    
  
    set -g remain-on-exit  
  
    set-hook -g pane-died 'capture-pane -S - -E - ; save-buffer "$HOME/logs/tmux/tmux-saved.#{host_short}-#{window_name}-#{window_id}:#{pane_id}-#{client_activity}.log"; delete-buffer; kill-pane; select-layout -E'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's exactly what you are looking for, but you could use the `capture-pane` command to save the contents of a pane (subject to what is still in the pane's history) to a file.

Comment: It is indeed not exactly what I'm looking for because my `tmux` is run on the `ssh` host not locally that means that I would have to copy the file after the session ends, but it is interesting I will try.

Comment: What you might want is to disable the alternate screen, although 1) I don't know how to do that and 2) I don't know if `tmux` uses it.

Comment: I think it is the role of the _terminal program_, or maybe that can be done by setting the `TERM` environment variable.